# How to read USSD messages in android?

Tags: android, api, ussd

I am developing an android application. I basically want to read the USSD responses into the application. Is there any API to do so? How to fetch these messages into application?

Comment: Check solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515906/how-to-read-ussd-messages-in-android/33964512#33964512

Comment: Check my anwser here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34132708/5603642

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no API for USSD request yet. The [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285) to create this API is not closed. But the community has found several hacks how to add this feature to their applications.

1. The first approach is to parse a log. [Here](http://codepaste.ru/7545/) is where you can find a class that do this. And [here](http://it-kregi.ru/files/ussd_source.rar) is a test application that uses this class.
2. Also [there](http://commandus.com/blog/?p=58) is a second approach.

Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried these methods? Are they working?

Comment: AFAIR, I tried the first one with Gingerbread and it worked. I do not know about new versions.

Comment: @Yury is it working with android 4.2 ?? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285#c311 someone says the latest version of android broke the hack. But I don't know what "hack" he was talking about. Can you please post an update here, it will be great!

Comment: Sorry, this is not my repository and I can say nothing if it is working in Android 4.2.

Comment: Plz help in reading the USSD response in my android application.

Comment: I'm currently having no luck using the first approach on 4.4.4. The result message has apparently been removed from the log.

Comment: Also, the second approach isn't available on 4.2.2+ https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57120

Comment: Aaaand ticket is now closed. Not very well played, Google

Comment: sadly windows phone has this .... and that too via javascript !

Comment: You need root access to read the full log

Comment: so any one could help me with links to read the ussd to track the mobile prepaid balance.

Comment: Please guide on how do i use the second approach..

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34132708/5603642