# Can the android API be used to intercept and read operator messages (USSD messages)?

Tags: android

Through the android API  is it possible for an android application to read the message sent by the mobile network operator as and when the user receives it as shown in the message below. If so how?:

[image: Operator message regarding data usage in Android]

Comment: The correct term is USSD. And No, android dont have an api for that. some suggested other option which you might want to take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515906/how-to-read-ussd-messages-in-android

Comment: Feature Request: Add USSD API support http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, it's not possible do interact with USSD though the Android SDK:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

Answer (score 0):

How about [this one](http://commandus.com/blog/?p=58) which is used by [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melkote.quietbalance) and [people reports](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1645339) that it works?

At the same time on Google Play, in app description one will find that it will not work with 4.2.2+ devices ;(