# How to get result of intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to access result of *#0228# (I use samsung galaxy i9000, maybe its for samsung..) I can  call this number with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ "*" + Uri.encode("#") + "0228" + Uri.encode("#")));
startActivity(intent);
```

It calls *#0228# after I can see battery info and gsm info (i.e. hsdpa)

I want to get these information as instant. I dont know what is the best way for it.
you know, it will always open some activitiy and will close and i will get info. maybe there must be another and easy way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of information you want you should look at 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

I don't think it's possible to intercept the result of USSD calls ( as described here: [Can the android API be used to intercept and read operator messages (USSD messages)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820853/can-the-api-intercept-and-read-operator-messages) ) and I also don't think it's necessary especially for the info that you seem to look for (gsm and battery info).

Comment: thank you for your explanation about ussd. I didnt know that there is no any api. Actually i didnt even know name is ussd :) and yes there is telephonymanager.. I think i will use this. But I was thinking that something is special for samsung, such as:  #*197328640*#  thank you again

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution here too:

[How to read USSD messages in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515906/how-to-read-ussd-messages-in-android)

Some guys hacked the ussd class. but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Y doesn t provide a correct battery voltage, But the ussd call *#0228# is correct.
The only way for me was to access to /sys/class/power_supply/battery/volt