# android how to display USSD reply in Toast

Tags: android, ussd

I've created running USSD function as follow

```
protected void call(String phoneNumber) {
    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"
                        + phoneNumber)), 1);
    } catch (Exception eExcept) {
        this.view.append("\n\n " + "\n" + eExcept.toString());
    }
}
```

above function, USSD reply message display in built-in dialog box. But I want to display reply message to Toast. And I want to go back after flash message. Below is coding for display reply message. But don't know how to go back after all.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    USSD ussd = new USSD(4000, 4000);
    if (ussd.IsFound())
        this.view.append("\n" + ussd.getMsg());
    else
        this.view.append("" + R.string.error_ussd_msg);

}
```

Comment: I think reply of ussd is a flash message

Comment: you may follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515906/how-to-read-ussd-messages-in-android

Comment: how to go back after that? I've edited my question.